# When are two elements of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ "iso-associates"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ denote a commutative ring. Then two elements of $R$ are said to be *associates* iff they generate the same ideal.

> **General question.** What do we call two elements of $R$ satisfying the weaker condition that the rings obtained by quotienting out by the corresponding ideals are isomorphic?
>
> Alternatively, what do we call two ideals that yield the same quotient ring up to isomorphism?

For the sake of readability, lets call any two such elements 'iso-associates.'

For example, in the ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$, we have the following.

- Given $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, the polynomial $x-a$ is an associate of $x-b$ iff $a=b$. Yet $x-a$ and $x-b$ are *always* iso-associates, because such quotient rings are always isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.
- Given $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, I think that the polynomial $x^2-a$ is an iso-associate of $x^2-b$ iff $\mathrm{sgn}(a) =\mathrm{sgn}(b)$. If I'm not mistaken, the three rings we can obtain in this way are the complex numbers, the hyperbolic numbers, and the dual numbers.

> **Specific question.** When are two elements of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ iso-associates?

Comment: Feels like for $\mathbb{C}[x]$ we would have $p(x)=\prod\limits_i (x-a_i)^{n_i}$ and $q(x)=\prod\limits_i (x-b_i)^{m_i}$ are iso-associates if they have isomorphic decompositions into irreducibles, that is if there exists a permutation $\pi$ such that $n_i = m_{\pi_i}$. In particular, the powers of $p$ and $q$ must coincide. For $\mathbb{R}[x]$ we'd have to consider irreducibles of the form $x^2+ax+b$ with negative determinant.

Answer (score 1):

Any $0\neq f\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ can uniquely be written as $f=ap_1^{r_1}\cdots p_k^{r_k}q_1^{s_1}\cdots q_l^{s_l}$ where $0\neq a\in\mathbb{R}$, $p_i=x-a_i$ for distinct $a_i\in \mathbb{R}$, $q_i$s are irreducible monic polynomials of degree 2, all distinct, $r_i,s_i\geq 1$, integers. Thus, we can associate to such an $f$, the set $(k(f),l(f), p_i(f), q_i(f), r_i(f), s_i(f))$. Then, $f$ is iso-associate to $g$ if the corresponding set for $g$ is the same. The proof is a simple application of Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: The $p_i$ and $q_i$ should not be part of the data, since they don't matter; all that matters is how many there are of each degree and multiplicity.

Comment: @EricWofsey You are right, I put too many things there.